# Can Power BI power query be connected to a source of another Power BI report?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Is it possible in Power BI power query to connect from A.pbix report to the results of other B.pbix report? If so, how? The reason for doing this is that in A.pbix we have one sort of aggregation - say many monthly reports for one country, and in B.pbix we have another, second stage, sort of aggregation - say one report for all countries.

There are reasons for keeping it separated - tidiness, possibility to refresh single source, lower memory used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option for this architecture is to publish B.pbix to a Workspace in the web service (app.powerbi.com) and then start A.pbix by connecting to the B.pbix dataset via Online Services / Power BI service.

That will make the entire dataset from B.pbix available for re-use.  You only need to worry about query / model maintenance and refresh on the B.pbix dataset. Varying visuals on the report pages you build in A.pbix and B.pbix should meet your requirements.

It's described in some detail here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-report-lifecycle-datasets

Comment: Is it possible to plug into data of specific visual in the B.pbix report? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52079733/import-data-from-published-power-bi-specific-visual-to-another-power-bi-report

Comment: Not directly, it only exposes the data model components (data tables & measures). You would need to re-create the visual in A.pbix. You would be sure of having all the data to do so.