# How to change between iframes in Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, powerbi

I was trying to understand how to change between iframes in selenium webdriver, but I could not figure it out.
In the image ahead, is the iframe that I want to switch to:

Snapshot:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 //iframe[@class='viewer pbi-frame']
```

Should be a simple xpath using driver.switch_to.frame()

Or

```
 //iframe[@title='Power BI Report Viewer']
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to switch to the iframe you can use code like this:

```py
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("//iframe[@title='PowerBi Report Viewer']"))
```

When finished working inside the iframe you will have to switch back to the default content with

```py
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Answer (score 1):

The website is [Power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60098448/7429447) based, so to switch within the [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[title='PowerBi Report Viewer']")))
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@title='PowerBi Report Viewer']")))
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: How to swtich to default frame?