# Scraping data from an online Power BI dashboard

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, powerbi, puppeteer

My local government has thrown the idea of open public data into the bin and chosen instead to publish its COVID-19 updates via an online Power BI dashboard (with no download option). The dashboard lacks a static `url`, but you can [access it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52079733/data-scraping-from-published-power-bi-visual).

When published online, Power BI dashboards have a complex HTML structure that doesn't seem to respond to scrapers like a normal `HTML` doc.

Using [Puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) (a Node.js module), I can scrape some elements from the first page of the dashboard. What I really need is to access the second page. To get this, I need to 'click' on the right arrow at the bottom of the screen. This can be selected successfully with `document.querySelector(".pbi-glyph-chevronrightmedium")`.

However, I can't *interact* with that element to reach the second page. While Puppeteer can find it, it can't click it. The first line here works; the second doesn't:

```
await page.waitForSelector(".pbi-glyph-chevronrightmedium");
await page.click(".pbi-glyph-chevronrightmedium");
```

Any ideas? There was another question published about [scraping from a Power BI dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55063265/scraping-data-from-a-website-which-uses-power-bi-retrieving-data-from-power-bi) but it covered different aspects. I can't perform the simple task of clicking the 'Next page' arrow.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
async function scrape() {
  var browser = await puppeteer.launch(),
      page = await browser.newPage();
  return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
    try {
      await page.goto("https://www.covid19.act.gov.au/updates/confirmed-case-information");
      await page.waitForSelector(".col-md-12 a");
      let dashboardUrl = await page.evaluate(function() {
        return document.querySelector(".col-md-12 a").href;
      });
      await page.goto(dashboardUrl);
      await page.waitForSelector(".pbi-glyph-chevronrightmedium");
      console.log("Found the arrow!");
      await page.click(".pbi-glyph-chevronrightmedium");
      console.log("Clicked the arrow!");
      browser.close();
      return resolve("end scrape");
    } catch (error) {
      return reject(error);
    }
  });
}
scrape()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
await page.click(".pbi-glyph-chevronrightmedium");
```

use

```
await page.$eval(".pbi-glyph-chevronrightmedium", el => el.click());
```

[(source)](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3347)

Comment: Brilliant — thank you! I'm surprised by this solution, though. In my script (not the one above), I had already used `page.evaluate()` on the page before this point. I was also able to click on other page elements successfully without using the `.evaluate()` method. Is this a long-standing but unresolved bug?